# How to get value from DAO and transfer it to JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm adding data to DB, but if record exists I wanna return an information in JSP file "Record already exist". I don't get it how to handle it in Java. I'm still learning...
Thats my DAO save method (btw is it possible to make it on one PreparedStatement ? I've 2 queries because I had to separate Insert and Select:

```
public void save(Event e) {
    PreparedStatement stm = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    try {
        String query = "select room_number, description, event_date, eventend_date, screen from events where not exists (select * from events where ((? between event_date and eventend_date) OR (? between event_date and eventend_date) OR (? <= event_date and ? >= eventend_date)) AND room_number = ?)";
        stmt = DatabaseConnector.getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
        Timestamp startDate11 = new Timestamp(e.getEventDate().getTime());
        stmt.setTimestamp(1, startDate11);
        Timestamp endDate11 = new Timestamp(e.getEventEndDate().getTime());
        stmt.setTimestamp(2, endDate11);
        stmt.setTimestamp(3, startDate11);
        stmt.setTimestamp(4, endDate11);
        stmt.setString(5, e.getRoomNumber());
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next()) {
            String sql = "insert into events (room_number, description, event_date, eventend_date, screen) values (?,?,?,?,?)";
            stm = DatabaseConnector.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
            //stm.setInt(1, e.getEventId());
            stm.setString(1, e.getRoomNumber());
            stm.setString(2, e.getDescription());
            Timestamp startDate = new Timestamp(e.getEventDate().getTime());
            stm.setTimestamp(3, startDate);
            Timestamp endDate = new Timestamp(e.getEventEndDate().getTime());
            stm.setTimestamp(4, endDate);
            stm.setString(5, e.getScreen());
            stm.executeUpdate();      
        } else {
            System.out.println("Record alrdy exist"); <- I wanna transfer that information to JSP.              
        }   
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            stm.close(); stmt.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }
}
```

That's my doGet servlet:

```
Event ev = new Event();
            request.setAttribute("events", ev);
            request.setAttribute("action", "new");
            request.getRequestDispatcher("JSP/AddNew.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

That's my doPost servlet:
Event ev = new Event();

```
            ev.setDescription(request.getParameter("description"));
            ev.setRoomNumber(request.getParameter("room"));
            ev.setScreen(request.getParameter("screen"));

            try {
                String startDateStr = request.getParameter("startDate");
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
                Date startDate = sdf.parse(startDateStr);
                ev.setEventDate(startDate);
                String endDateStr = request.getParameter("endDate");
                Date endDate = sdf.parse(endDateStr);
                ev.setEventEndDate(endDate);

            } catch (ParseException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ActionOnEventsController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            eDao.save(ev);

            response.sendRedirect("userpanel");
```

And I've standard JSP file with few input called AddNew.jsp.
My 'save' method works good but I don't have an idea how to tell user that he didn't add event to DB because event already exists :/

Comment: you could always add a parameter to the response and get that parameter inside of your JSP

Answer (score 0):

You can return an error message from `save()` in case of failure and check if you getting some non-null, set an attribute in the request and forward to jsp.

Comment: I still don't know how to handle this. How can I tell user that he did or didn't add an event. Couldn't find any example ;/